# UICollectionView resizing itself by 1 pixel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in which each cell is 320x195px, and there are no separators between cells.

Inside each cell, I've put a `UICollectionView` to take up the entire cell, which is also 320x195 and contains `UICollectionViewCell`s which are also 320x195px. In Interface Builder I've specified all section insets, min spacing, header and footer sizes all to 0, and specified that the layout should flow horizontally.

What I've found is that when this runs, each cell in my table has a black line under it. Using the fantastic [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) framework I traced this issue down to the fact that the `UICollectionView` is seemingly resizing itself to 320 x **196px** at runtime, causing a 1px gap at the bottom of each cell. Both the `UITableViewCell` and the inner `UICollectionView` cell remain at 320x195, but the `UICollectionView` is resizing itself and adding 1px to its height.

I can't for the life of me figure out what might be causing the `UICollectionView` to resize itself like this. For now what I've done is change the size of my `UICollectionView` to 320 x **194px** so that now when it adds the 1px it at least comes out at the right height and prevents the black gap at the bottom -- but this is a cheat, and I'd rather know the root cause of this so I know for next time.

The only thing that might be related to this is that my root `UITableViewCell` has a subview which is the "Content View" (as all `UITableViewCell`s are seemingly forced to have), and IB tells me that the size of this view is 320x194 (and any options to adjust this are greyed out).

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and it's annoying since I'm afraid that if I resize to fix it, it'll silently go away in a future update and break things again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and found the reason: in my case it's because the instance of the UICollectionView's y-position was on a pixel fraction, like 10.5
My solution: round the y-position to a whole number (10)